# Serial Port Data Loss (Hardware FIFO Overrun) after PC wake-up

Tags: linux, serial-port, linux-device-driver, data-loss

In a serial RS-232/UART transmission from a µC to a PC, I am having problems with data loss (FIFO overruns) after wake-up of the PC.

- "PC" is the receiver, a ThinkPad T400 laptop running "Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS".
- "µC" is the sender, a bare-metal micro-controller (AVR ATmega168) connected via MAX232* to the PC.

The communication works fine after booting or re-starting the PC, but when I am closing the lid of the laptop, wait a minute or so, and then waking it up, there is data loss that looks like FIFO overruns for messages that are sent after wake-up.

In order to monitor the serial line I am using [`picocom`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/picocom) terminal program:

```
> picocom --baud 115200 --parity none --databits 8 --stopbits 1 /dev/ttyS0
```

The output of picocom is as follows:

```
picocom v3.1
port is        : /dev/ttyS0
flowcontrol    : none
baudrate is    : 115200
parity is      : none
databits are   : 8
stopbits are   : 1
escape is      : C-a
local echo is  : no
noinit is      : no
noreset is     : no
hangup is      : no
nolock is      : no
send_cmd is    : sz -vv
receive_cmd is : rz -vv -E
imap is        : 
omap is        : 
emap is        : crcrlf,delbs,
logfile is     : none
initstring     : none
exit_after is  : not set
exit is        : no

Type [C-a] [C-h] to see available commands
Terminal ready

8|123456789|123456789|
9|123456789|123456789|
10|123456789|123456789|
11|123456789|123456789|
12|123456789|123456789|
13|123456789|123456789|
76|123456789|1
77|123456789|1
78|123456789|1
79|123456789|1|
80|123456789|1
81|123456789|1
82|123456789|1
83|123456789|1
84|123456789|1
85|123456789|1
...
```

The µC is sending one message each second, the respective part of the C program is:

```cpp
    printf ("\n%d|123456789|123456789|", ++count);
```

The PC was inactive for `count` in 14...75. Messages up to count = 13 are complete. PC woke up at count = 76, and after wake-up messages are truncated to 16 bytes.

```
> sudo cat /proc/tty/driver/serial
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:16550A port:000003F8 irq:4 tx:0 rx:1389 oe:15
```

The `oe` counts the overrun errors. After wake-up, the messages are truncated after 16 bytes (newline takes 2 bytes).

**Question:** How can I work around this error? Is there a way to "restart" the serial port or the kernel module that is responsible for servicing the IRQs without restarting the PC?

What I have tried so far and what did *not* work:

- Use different terminal programs like `minicom` or `pyserial-miniterm` from PySerial.
- Setting low latency flag as of `setserial /dev/ttyS0 low_latency`.
- Using smaller baud-rate like 9600.
- Closing and re-opening `picocom`.
- Running `stty -F /dev/ttyS0 sane`.

Also there is a perceivable jitter when the broken messages are displayed by the terminal program, even though the µC is sending them at exact 1-second intervals.

As far as I understand, the [16550A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16550_UART) has a 16-byte FIFO, and it will trigger an IRQ when the FIFO is filled up to a specific portion like 1 or 4 or 14 bytes. It seems the PC is no more servicing the IRQ 4 after wake-up, or the 16550A is no more raising IRQs?

Some more data from [`setserial`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/setserial) and [`stty`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stty):

```
> setserial /dev/ttyS0 -a
/dev/ttyS0, Line 0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
    Baud_base: 115200, close_delay: 50, divisor: 0
    closing_wait: 3000
    Flags: spd_normal skip_test low_latency
```

```
> stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -a
speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>;
swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V;
discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany
-imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
-flusho -extproc
```

What I also tried is to use Xon/Xoff software flow-control, but the PC won't send `^S`.  Which is presumably because linux's serial buffer is several kBytes in size, and that buffer is never anywhere near to full.  And if the PC is not working correct to read out the FIFO in time, it would also not be able to send `^S` in time.

Hardware flow-control is not an option, because the µC board just has TxD and RxD connected.

Comment: I HW flow control is not an option, you have to bear with the current behaviour. There is nothing can be done. UART is not master-slave, but peer-to-peer and with very small FIFO. Modern General Purpose OSes are not able to handle it anyway (too much resources are needed). Options are: 1) flow control; 2) another type of interface (SPI?); 3) switching to RTOS on PC; 4) pinning one CPU (core) for UART job (waste of resources, though).

Comment: "you have to bear with the current behaviour": What confuses me is that the OS / PC can handle it, even at a rate much higher than 1 message/sec like 100 msg/sec is absolutely no problem BEFORE PC went to sleep.  What I observed is that `watch -n0.1 head -5 /proc/interrupts` show +4 IRQ4 / sec before sleep, but only +1 IRQ4 / sec after sleep. So there is definitely a difference in OS behaviour or IRQ setup. Ad 4) How would I pin one core to the UART job (and unpin in again)?

Comment: 4) use IRQ affinity setting of the UART interrupt to it.

Comment: So, try to find what changes during the sleep. Any configuration of the pins? Any internal states of the kernel (related to tty/UART)? Canonical vs. raw vs. another mode of termios? Maybe UART is not sleeping and that's why its FIFO is full when OS wakes up. Have you tried to flush the UART buffers before reading from them?

Comment: Can you give any specific hints on how I can find the difference? Output of `setserial /dev/ttyS0 -a` is the same before and after sleep. Same for `stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -a`. There is the mentioned difference in `/proc/interrupts`, but how do I find the cause, lest fix it?

Comment: You can patch the 8250 driver to dump registers before sleep and immediately after resume. It looks like something is not restored correctly. If it's the case, does the rerun a program on PC side (after resume from sleep) fix the issue?

Comment: Problem is that you cannot read back most registers.  For example, FCR (FIFO Control Register) is at the same address like IIR (Interrupt Identify Register) are at the same address 0x3fa. Write to that address will write FCR, but read will get IIR. I found that permanently reading 16550A scratch register SCR at 0x3ff changes behaviour, presumably because it triggers scheduling of the picocom thread.  I get more and more the impression that it's a linux driver issue, nor a hardware config issue.

Comment: You may dump what is programmed to them, right? Also note that there is a cache inside the driver to keep those values for software need. Just read a bit of code in 8250_port.c and 8250_core.c.

Comment: How would I apply the changes to that file? If I compiled it to `8250_port.o`, what do I do with the object file?